# JETTY Server Error:404 on Ubuntu, Geoserver

Tags: java, ubuntu, jetty, http-status-code-404, geoserver

I am attempting to run (Jetty) Geoserver 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 using Open JDK 8 on a machine which also contains Apache, MYSQL, and GDAL.  I followed the instructions from a nice denizen of the internet named [Jeff](https://funnymonkey.com/2011/installing-geoserver-on-ubuntu-1004).

Upon completion of his instructions, I run the following command in [GUAKE](https://github.com/Guake/guake) Shell to start up Geoserver:

> sudo /etc/init.d/geoserver start

I then (without quitting the terminal) open Firefox and type in the following URL:

http://localhost:8080

Firefox shows the following **404** error:

[image]

I also attempted appending `/geoserver` and `/geoserver/web` to the URL, which changed my error from **404** to **503** (making progress!).

I get the same error(s) when I use the built-in Ubuntu shell instead of GUAKE.  I have, per answers on similar questions, confirmed that geoserver is indeed running on 8080 (and that nothing else is).  I have attempted using Tomcat7, and while I was able to get a successful 8080 page with Tomcat7, it was not the geoserver page - and the geoserver urls (`/geoserver` and `/geoserver/web`) still did not work.

EDIT: Here is the geoserver.log:

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the Log information generated by Jetty?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the Jetty log.  I apologize for my ignorance!  That said, I am adding the geoserver.log as an edit, and perhaps that will illuminate something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those directions have two issues which may cause some trouble:  First, they are out-of-date, and second, they are installing a number of additional plugins.  From the screencap, the error at the bottom could be related to the ogr plugin.

I'd recommend checking out the GeoServer [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux.html) for using Jetty on Linux; it will have you download the latest version of Geoserver [here](http://geoserver.org/release/stable/).

The directions you mentioned might help with setting up Jetty as a service, etc.  The GeoServer documentation should help get GeoServer up and running; if you have other questions about plugins, we can go from there.

Comment: It will take a day or two to verify that this is the correct answer due to my schedule at work, but upon completion of reinstalling using geoserver docs etc I will come back and accept the answer if you're right (which I suspect you are). Thanks!